# Angular ngRepeat on resource. Focus lost on update of resource

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that uses ngRepeat over a collection of objects in a resource. When any field is changed on the object the resource is posted to the server and the collection of objects is returned again by the server and updated on the model. This causes the ngRepeat to re-render and focus to be lost on the currently editing field. Is there a way to check in the resource whether anything has changed between the data sent to the server and that returned and only update the model if it is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "track by".  If your resource items have a specific id it would be

```
ng-repeat="item in resource.items track by item.id"
```

This will prevent angular from rerendering items it has already rendered, and should preserve the state of your DOM.

Comment: We are already using that. Sorry I haven't posted code, it is quite a complicated setup. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

add attribute set-focus-if=""

```
directive('setFocusIf', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.$watch($attr.setFocusIf, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        // We must reevaluate the value in case it was changed by a subsequent
                        // watch handler in the digest.
                        if ($scope.$eval($attr.setFocusIf)) {
                            $element[0].focus();
                        }
                    }, 0, false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue we may decide to wrap resource in our own service. Our service will do the manual differencing and only update the model if anything has changed.